# how to store iphones apps on Apple Store

Tags: ios4

i have developed iphone app, and it has been tested on iphone simulator, now i want to run my application on the iphone device, for that i need to store my app on the Apple store.
How can i move my iphone-apps on the Apple Store?
Plz Help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the iOS developer program. See http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/

Once you join the program, you will be able to install your app on your device without going through the App Store.  You don't submit it to the App Store until it is fully tested and ready for sale.